# How to extract and combine multiple json files from multiple sub folders into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Can someone help me out with the following:

I have a folder that contains levels of sub folders, which each contain several json files. I have been using the following code to extract them all and join them into a dataframe:

```
PATH = ("C:/Users/77901898/Documents/.../11 - Trial run")
EXT = ("*.json")

json_files = []
for path, subdir, files in os.walk(PATH):
    for file in glob(os.path.join(path, EXT)):
        json_files.append(file)

df = pd.concat([pd.read_json (file) for file in json_files], ignore_index = True)
```

But I am getting the following error: "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

I have also tried the implementation from this question:
[How to read multiple json files into pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57067551/how-to-read-multiple-json-files-into-pandas-dataframe)
but it throws up "ValueError: No objects to concatenate"

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: It's possible that you are not getting the right json filename when you do `glob(os.path.join(path, EXT))` try to print the value of `file`. According to os.walk documentation "To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name)." IN your case, the variable names would be path and files  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk